# using web3js on a server without geth or any client

Tags: web3js, nodejs

related to [for using web3.js it is necessary to install geth into your system](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25449/for-using-web3-js-it-is-necessary-to-install-geth-into-your-system)

I want to use web3js with nodejs server to get interact with a smartcontract deployed on rinkeby/mainnet. Do I need to setup geth on my server and sync all the rinkeby/mainnet data to use web3 with nodejs or I can interact without setting up geth?

Comment: The first answer from the link you provide has the answer. You do not need to install geth, you can use a third party service like infura.io.

Comment: awesome @ismael. I already mentioned in my question that this is related to another question however i wanted answer for server but other question assumes local usage.

Comment: The answer is the same, you do not need to install geth you can use a third party service.

Answer (score 0):

You need a client, like geth, to get the chain information.

You can also get the http provider from an other node that has a JSON-RPC endpoint openned.

Comment: is there any http provider for ethereum mainnet and rinkeby?

Comment: I beleive etherscan and metamask are possible options.

Comment: isnt metamask browser based? i want to interact on server side. not client side

Comment: Metamask obviously has a server. please use google.

Comment: By default, I believe MetaMask uses [Infura](https://infura.io). So no, they don't have a server.

Comment: By default, people should make research before. His question has been, I beleive, asked many times. Just take 15 minutes and use google.